# iOS application to show the battery charging rate in mA

Tags: ios, battery

I am looking for an iOS application that can show the battery charging rate in mA. Free if possible, and supporting iOS 7.1

Answer (score 3):

The [Tesla Model S](http://appcrawlr.com/ios/tesla-model-s) app does exactly this. It shows battery charging rate for your car rather than your phone, though, which might not be exactly what you wanted.

[image]

Edit: the app is free, but the car is not...

Comment: The funniest recommendation of the week.

Comment: @Deer Hunter I'm feeling utter remorse, so I'm actually looking pretty hard for some constructive answer.

Comment: I guess this explains the 80A that surprised me at first. So yeah I'm looking for the iPhone's battery charging rate, but please keep the answer in case I drive a Tesla someday :)

Answer (score 0):

The app ChargerTesting does this now.
https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/ampere-charger-testing/id1438386754

It’s clever, has a few usability glitches, and Takes a while to produce a result, which should be taken as a ballpark figure rather than anything precise. But it does give you an idea what’s going on.